# Unupvote loses you more rep than downvote

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, feedback

User A has 5 reputation.  User A posts an answer and receives:

upvote +10 **then**
unupvote -10 ***rep = 5*** (neutral feedback)

upvote + 10 **then**
downvote -2  ***rep = 13*** (negative feedback)

How come user A ends up with *more* rep when he receives negative feedback than when he receives neutral feedback (essentially no feedback)

Is this a problem?

Comment: This is normal.  Upvote is +10 rep.  If this is cancelled, the +10 is undone.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How come user A ends up with more rep when he receives negative feedback than when he receives neutral feedback (essentially no feedback)

A single user can't both up-, down- and not vote all at once, on a single post. You can upvote and unupvote/downvote shortly after, but that cancels your upvote. So, starting with user A and B:

If user A receives negative feedback from user B, their reputation would be 3, and they **would** end up with less reputation than they'd have with no feedback at all. 
If user A receives no feedback (or an upvote/unupvote, downvote/undownvote) from user B, their reputation would remain 5. 
If user A receives positive feedback from user B, their reputation goes up by 10 points to 15.

After having received positive feedback, A is at 15 reputation. Then user C comes in, with negative feedback, and A ends up with 13 reputation. Which is less than the 15 they started with before the negative feedback. So the negative feedback did cost them reputation.

The error in your calculation is that you assume `an upvote + a downvote = negative feedback`, while you should think of it as only `downvote = 'negative feedback'`.

Comment: A single user can up-, down- and not!

Comment: @Lordology not all at once. If you've upvoted something you can downvote it but that cancels the upvote. I'll clarify.

Answer (score 2):

### No, it is not a problem.

You **earn** reputation when:

- +1: You cancel your own downvote
- +2: Suggested edit is accepted // you accept an answer // downvote is removed from your question or answer
- +5: Your question is upvoted
- +10: Your answer is upvoted
- +15: Your answer is accepted
- +Half bounty amount: One of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically
- +Full bounty amount: Bounty awarded to your answer
- +100: Association Bonus

You **lose** reputation when:

- -1: You downvote an answer
- -2: Your question or answer is downvoted // you cancel your own accept on an answer // approved edit is reverted
- -5: Upvote is removed from your question
- -10: Upvote is removed from your answer
- -15: Accept is removed from your answer
- -Half bounty amount: **This will not actually happen**
- -Full bounty amount: You place a bounty on a question
- -100: Your post is marked as inappropriate

---

All users start with one reputation point, and reputation can never drop below 1. Accepting your own answer does not increase your reputation. Deleted posts do not affect reputation, for voters, authors or anyone else involved, in most cases. If a user reverses a vote, the corresponding reputation loss or gain will be reversed as well.  In fact, it is normal for an un-upvote to cost more reputation than a downvote.